# How can I run multiple Haskell IO actions and store the results?

Tags: haskell

I'm a Haskell beginner, so sorry in advance for the newbie question. I only have a very superficial understanding of monads.

I'm using the function `insert` from the module Persistent. (I've been following [the tutorial here](https://www.yesodweb.com/book/persistent).) It inserts something in a database, and returns the ID. I can use it like this:

```
resultId <- insert myItem
```

That works fine for a single item. I can print out the resultId like this:

```
liftIO $ print resultId
```

But what if my `myItem` is actually a list of arbitrary length? I want to map `insert` over this list, which I can seem to do with:

```
resultIds <- mapM_ insert myItemList
```

but then if I try to print out the values:

```
liftIO $ print resultIds
```

I just get `()`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should use `mapM` instead of `mapM_` the underscore means that you do not care about the result.

Comment: Cool, thanks, that did it.

Comment: To elaborate, `mapM_` discards the result, replacing it with `()`. It's useful in certain contexts but not here, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are quite close: you need [**`mapM :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> t a -> m (t b)`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mapM) instead of [**`mapM_ :: (Foldable t, Monad m) => (a -> m b) -> t a -> m ()`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mapM_)

Like the name and the signature already suggest, both functions take a monadic function and a traversable (let us for now assume that that is a list) of `a`s, and it applies the monadic function to all elements and returns a monadic function that contains a traversable (list) of the results.

So if you write:

```
    resultIds <- mapM insert myItemList
```

The difference between `mapM` and `mapM_` is that in the case of `mapM_` (like the signature already suggests), you are not interested in the outcome, and thus it is not calculated. A reason for this could possibly be that the list is very long (and generated *by-need*), and thus the list of identifiers would never fit in memory.

then `resultIds` will contain a list of identifiers.

The explanation about the `mapM` (and `mapM_`) function is a bit an oversimplification, but I think that it is usually better to first get more comfortable about monads, than getting details about monadic functions completely right.